# How do I stop Twilio making multiple requests on an incoming call?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I've got a pretty standard set-up: Twilio number -> AWS API Gateway -> Lambda, so it hits the Lambda function when the call goes through. The function then returns some TWIML to record the call:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="alice">You have reached the voicemail of {insert number here}. Please leave a message after the beep.</Say>
    <Record transcribe="false" playBeep="true" recordingStatusCallback="https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/recordingstatus" recordingStatusCallbackMethod="POST"/>
    <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

I figured this would then cause Twilio to make another request once the recording is done to the above URL, but it's causing two further requests to be made: One to the above URL (which triggers a separate Lambda function with the recording status and the URL of the recording) and one to the original incoming call URL with a status of `hangup`, along with the recording status and the recording URL.

I don't want it to trigger the same Lambda function again (trying to keep things separate), so is it possible to stop Twilio requesting the incoming call URL when the call is complete?

Answer (score 0):

The `recordingStatusCallbackEvent` property should do the magic for you when you set it to `in-progress` or `completed`.

Here's a link to the [docs] for more details.(https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-recording-status-callback-event)